# TCL global vs. variable access speed

Tags: namespaces, tcl, global

In TCL, roughly, there are the global variables, accessible via the `global varname`, or namespace variables accessible via the `namespace varname` command.
My very simple checking of access time for the 2 shows a tiny, but consistent runtime access advantage for the `variable` vs. the `global`, for version tcl 8.5.
Can we expect this to be the case for 8.6 and above, at least for now?

Comment: Could you show us how did you test it? And what kind of difference you got?

Comment: I just set 2 variables, one namespace, one global.
Then I had 2 namespace procs, which declared the variables (one the global, the other namespace), and then returned the value. I then used the time command, with 100000 iterations. The difference, on my system, was consistently ~0.8% in runtime, the namespace slightly faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** There's *very* little difference in speed between the two, not enough that you should care. Do things in a way that is semantically correct and leave it at that. Being correct *for your use case* will beat any tinkering with fractions of a percent in terms of timing.

---

Let's compare the following two procedures in the global namespace *that do the same thing*. Note that the weight of the difference between the options we are comparing is going to be artificially raised relative to real code; these are microbenchmarks and should rightfully be treated with suspicion.

```
proc a {} {
    global x y
    expr {$x + $y}
}

proc b {} {
    variable x
    variable y
    expr {$x + $y}
}
```

OK, the timing info (your absolute timings *will* vary according to hardware):

```
% set x 123
123
% set y 456
456
% a
579
% b
579
% time { a } 10000
0.5720533 microseconds per iteration
% time { b } 10000
0.5756787999999999 microseconds per iteration
```

So yes, `b` is slightly slower than `a`. Let's look at the bytecodes to see why:

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble proc a
ByteCode 0x0x10280fe10, refCt 1, epoch 15, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 15)
  Source "\n    global x y\n    expr {$x + $y"...
  Cmds 2, src 35, inst 35, litObjs 4, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x0x102822c10, refCt 1, args 0, compiled locals 2
      slot 0, scalar, "x"
      slot 1, scalar, "y"
  Commands 2:
      1: pc 0-19, src 5-14        2: pc 20-33, src 20-33
  Command 1: "global x y"...
    (0) push1 0     # "::"
    (2) push1 1     # "x"
    (4) nsupvar %v0     # var "x"
    (9) push1 2     # "y"
    (11) nsupvar %v1    # var "y"
    (16) pop 
    (17) nop 
    (18) nop 
    (19) nop 
  Command 2: "expr {$x + $y}"...
    (20) startCommand +14 1     # next cmd at pc 34, 1 cmds start here
    (29) loadScalar1 %v0    # var "x"
    (31) loadScalar1 %v1    # var "y"
    (33) add 
    (34) done 

% tcl::unsupported::disassemble proc b
ByteCode 0x0x10280fa10, refCt 1, epoch 15, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 15)
  Source "\n    variable x\n    variable y\n    expr {$x + $"...
  Cmds 3, src 50, inst 44, litObjs 3, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x0x102822a90, refCt 1, args 0, compiled locals 2
      slot 0, scalar, "x"
      slot 1, scalar, "y"
  Commands 3:
      1: pc 0-9, src 5-14        2: pc 10-28, src 20-29
      3: pc 29-42, src 35-48
  Command 1: "variable x"...
    (0) push1 0     # "x"
    (2) variable %v0    # var "x"
    (7) nop 
    (8) nop 
    (9) nop 
  Command 2: "variable y"...
    (10) startCommand +18 1     # next cmd at pc 28, 1 cmds start here
    (19) push1 2    # "y"
    (21) variable %v1   # var "y"
    (26) push1 1    # ""
    (28) pop 
  Command 3: "expr {$x + $y}"...
    (29) startCommand +14 1     # next cmd at pc 43, 1 cmds start here
    (38) loadScalar1 %v0    # var "x"
    (40) loadScalar1 %v1    # var "y"
    (42) add 
    (43) done
```

The exact bytecode sequence might be different in your version of Tcl; that's totally part of the implementation, not the official interface. However, we can see that with `global` the opcode sequence involves a single `push1` of a namespace handle and two `nsupvar`s inside the implementation of the command, and with the two `variable` calls, the namespace isn't pushed but the `variable` opcode is used twice and there's an extra `startCommand` between the two. The `startCommand` is a messy piece of infrastructure that has a side effect of suppressing some minor optimisations, so that might be the cause.

With such a small difference between the two, working out where the performance differences really are is going to require instrumentation like cachegrind…

BTW, try comparing the performance with this:

```
proc c {} {
    namespace upvar :: x x y y
    expr {$x + $y}
}
```

That has an *exactly identical* bytecode sequence to the `a` procedure above…